# New Entry of Data overwrites all past entries in column , how do i correct this?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, database-design

Using Django,

when the User fills out the webform, one of the saved Data overwrites all pass entered data for that column. How do i stop it from overwriting it the other past data for that column ?

Models.py file below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 




class ansquestions(models.Model):
    m_invested = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    p_return = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inflation_yes_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    results = models.ForeignKey('results', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) # null=True
    

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.m_invested + ' ' +self.p_return




class results(models.Model): # second table for output and add other data from ansquestions table as foreign keys
    r_output = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.r_output
    # Important : this dunder method above __str__(self) for r_ouptput was how the actual r_output value gets displayed on admin interface. important since it was foreign key
```

Here are the first 2 View Functions

```
# functions investmenttest and add are together 
def investmenttest(request):
    return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmenttest.html')


# functions investmentfv and investmentfvcalc (real application)
# the html files that im using and have the css on them are home.html , about.html , investmentfv.html , fvinvestmentcalcresults.html(this outputs the result answer, as you see function below)  
# CSS files are under the static folder , sub-folder "design"
def investmentfv(request):
    global total_i
    global perc_r
    global years_i
    global makeup_infl
    idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf }
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AnsquestionsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            total_i = request.POST.get("m_invested", '')
            perc_r = request.POST.get("p_return", '')
            years_i = request.POST.get("years", '')
            makeup_infl = request.POST.get("inflation_yes_no", '')        
            newdata=ansquestions(m_invested=total_i, p_return=perc_r, years=years_i, inflation_yes_no=makeup_infl) 
            #newdata.results = results.objects.latest('id')#Note latest() is query set operator. BK# results.objects.order_by( 'author', 'id', 'r_output').last()#this is method for getting latest r_output from results table                                         
            newdata.author = request.user         
            newdata.save()

            return redirect('formulafv')# redirects to formulafv view function below. 'formulafv' is the name variable for that url pattern.
    else:
        return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmentfv.html', idata)
    
    idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf, 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmentfv.html', idata)
```

Below is the View Function that im having problem with, This is where i'm having the trouble with the latest.objects('id') command, i found this as a solution, but it's overwriting all of the rows for that "Results" Column

```
def formulafv(request): 
    if makeup_infl=='no':
        i_return = (float(perc_r))
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)<=5:
        i_return = (2+float(perc_r))
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)>5 and int(years_i)<=9.99 :
        i_return = (4 + float(perc_r))
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and int(years_i)>= 10 :
        i_return = ( 6 + float(perc_r))

    fv_i_value = int(total_i) * (1 + (i_return)*.01) ** int(years_i)

    r_output = 'Your money would grow to the total of ' + str(fv_i_value) +' dollars at the end of this timeframe.' 

    if request.method == "POST": # second pre-filled html form for saving r_output. for right now have to press submit button on screen. (i would want this to automatically (save/submit).      
        tom = ResForm(request.POST or None)
        if tom.is_valid():
            r_output = request.POST.get("r_output", '')
            bamdata = results(r_output=r_output)
            bamdata.author = request.user
            bamdata.save()
            
          
           
            ansquestions.results = results.objects.latest('id')  
            
            dabby = ansquestions.results 
            dabby.author = request.user 
            dabby.save()
   
   

     finalcalc = {'r_output': r_output }
     return render (request,'fvalueapp/fvinvestmentcalcresults.html', finalcalc)
```

[image]

Comment: Your view has so many global variables it is unreadable. **Don't** use global variables with views, Store any necessary data in the database! Even unique values which keep changing you can just store them in a table having only one row. What is `ansquestions` (global variable)?

Comment: Oh it's your model name, as another note since Models are classes name them in Pascal Case, it is really difficult to differentiate them from variables if you give them lowercase names.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat i have added the first 2 view functions above, if that may also help clarify things.  thanks,

Comment: I don't think you have put the complete formulafv view, anyway in that view `ansquestions.results = ...`, what are you expecting? ansquestions is your model (not an instance of the model) why are you setting the results attribute on your model?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , in the ansquestions.results = ...., i'am trying to to put the latest value from the " r_output " field that is from the "Results Model" above.  The problem is that it overwrites the past entries with the most recent " r_output " .

Comment: Of course it will override! You have set it as a **class attribute** any future instances would have that value. You want to set it on an **instance of ansquestions** which you get by `ansquestions.objects.get(.....)`. Please check the answer by Daniel Hepper below, it would be useful to you.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat , i know of the other possible way to do as mentioned by Daniel below. But when you say ansquestions.objects.get(...), the problem with that is is the id number would have to be identified with a number that you manually type in. that is why the "latest.objects.id" takes care of that. So if your saying it can be done that way, than specifically, how would you do that ?

Comment: `bamdata.save()` this will return an instance of `results` so you can put it in a variable `my_result = bamdata.save()`, The issue as outlined in Daniel's answer is what happens with multiple users? Firstly your global variables will have **wrong** values (belonging to some other user), secondly if two users access this view with little time difference they may end up with the incorrect instance of results (again belonging to the other user).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at your question.
First, two things that were already noted in the comments:

1. Get rid of the global variables. Global variables will behave in unexpected ways in a Django application, you should not use them unless you really, really, really know what you are doing.
2. Capitalize your class names, i.e. Ansquestions and Results

With that out of the way. Let's try to figure out what's going on here. My understanding is that you want to collect some information about an investment and then calculate the returns.

Why is Results a separate model? It could be a field on your Ansquestions. You could store the string you want to display, or even better, just the numerical value.

Why is formulafv a separate view? You can do the calculation immediately when you receive the inputs.

`results.objects.latest('id')` will indeed give you the latest object. But once you have multiple users accessing your application, you will run into a race-conditions so you get the results from a different user. But you don't really need it here anyways.

Don't use request.POST directly, use form.cleaned_data. If your AnsquestionsForm uses FloatFields and IntegerFields, form.cleaned_data will contain floats and ints. You then don't need any conversions from str to int in formulafv

Here is some (untested) code to illustrate what I mean:

```
# models.py
class Ansquestions(models.Model):
    m_invested = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    p_return = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inflation_yes_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    results = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def investment_return(self):
        return 'Your money would grow to the total of {} dollars at the end of this timeframe.'.format(self.results)

# views.py
def investmentfv(request):
    idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf }
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = AnsquestionsForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            total_i = form.cleaned_data['m_invested']
            perc_r = form.cleaned_data["p_return"]
            years_i = form.cleaned_data["years"]
            makeup_infl = form.cleaned_data["inflation_yes_no"]
            results = formulafv(makeup_infl, years_i, perc_r, total_i)
            newdata=ansquestions(m_invested=total_i, p_return=perc_r, years=years_i, inflation_yes_no=makeup_infl, results=results) 
            newdata.author = request.user         
            newdata.save()

            return redirect('formulafv')# redirects to formulafv view function below. 'formulafv' is the name variable for that url pattern.
    else:
        return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmentfv.html', idata)
    
    idata = { 'tmi':tmi, 'pry':pry, 'ys':ys, 'qinf':qinf, 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'fvalueapp/investmentfv.html', idata)

def formulafv(makeup_infl, years_i, perc_r, total_i):
    if makeup_infl=='no':
        i_return = perc_r
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and years_i<=5:
        i_return = 2 + perc_r
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and years_i>5 and years_i<=9.99 :
        i_return = 4 + perc_r
    elif makeup_infl=='yes' and years_i>= 10 :
        i_return = 6 + perc_r

    fv_i_value = total_i * (1 + (i_return)*.01) ** years_i

    return fv_i_value

# admin.py
class AnsquestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [..., 'investment_return', ...]
```

Also, I would suggest using the same name for a field/variable in your model, form and views. That makes it much easier to understand what's going on. I have not done that in the code above to not change everything completely.

I hope that points you in the right direction.